# How to show only one state google maps with different color and each one should be clickable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps

I want to use Google Maps to display a state and I want every place in that state to be clickable. How can I do that using asp.net C#? For example I need to integrate [this kind of map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSlIj.jpg) on my website.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to implement [Custom Overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays#top_of_page) in your map and then implement `onClick` listeners on each `<div>` overlay that you have created.

Found this [guide](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-google-maps-api-and-custom-overlays--webdesign-13868) as a referrence on what and how the flow will be. Though not implemented using ASP, think you can still use this as a guide.